# mongodb- How to display a year from a date in find method

Tags: mongodb

Im trying to display the years of date properties in a mongodb collection.

I have collection of vehicles that contains objects with a date property:
manufacturingDate - Date (ISODate).

To display only the years there is one way to this with aggregate:

```
db.vehicles.aggregate(
    [
        { $project: { year: { $year: "$manufacturingDate" } } }
    ]
)
```

But I am not allowed to use aggregate so i need a way to take the year out of the ISODate in another way.

I have tried many things like:

```
db.vehicles.find({}, { manufacturingDate: { $year: 1 } } )
```

or:

```
db.vehicles.find({}, { year: { function() { return this.manufacturingDate.getFullYear() } } } )
```

But these are all syntax errors.
So i hope you have a correct way to do this without aggregate. I prefer the find method but any other method will be good.

Thanks.

Comment: Of course there are syntax errors. `.find()` cannot alter the document content in any way, only select fields in a very basic way. Only `.aggregate()` and `.mapReduce()` can return a representation of documents that is not what is stored, or calculate a value and return it as this basically asks. This is of course intentional. Use the other methods and not `.find()`.

Comment: I am not allowed to use the aggregate method. Can you show me how it can be done with mapReduce() please?

Comment: What do you mean "not allowed"? I'm not aware of permission level blocking of such methods. Do you mean your MongoDB version is less than 2.2? You actually show an agggregate call that does what you want. Or does "not allowed" refer to someone telling you not to use it. If so then they are being foolish and likely do not know what they are talking about.

Comment: And even when not being allowed, what is wrong with extracting the year on the application side? Since you request **all** documents, you will have to iterate over them, anyway, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways to do it. Of course; it would be nicer if we could just execute getFullYear within a forEach applied to the find() but this is what works for me so far.

1. I found this on [link]http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongodb-user/133nvkd48q/how-to-format-output-datetime and tweaked the example. Obviously there is more here than you need bu I left the extra bits for clarity.

//first create a function to handle the execution of the getFullYear function on the ISODate field.

```
function parse_date(obj) {
year = obj['manufacturingDate'].getFullYear();
month = obj['manufacturingDate'].getMonth() + 1;
day = obj['manufacturingDate'].getUTCDate();
hour = obj['manufacturingDate'].getUTCHours();
minute = obj['manufacturingDate'].getUTCMinutes();
obj['manufacturingDate'] = year + '/' + month + '/' + day + ' ' + hour + 
':' + minute
//printjson(obj);
printjson(year);
}

//then execute your query and apply the parse_date function above within   
the forEach of the find method.
db.sample.find({},{manufacturingDate:1}).forEach(parse_date)
```

2. You can also iterate over the resultset as a cursor and applying the getFullYear function against the ISODate field.

   //iterate over cursor
     var mdate = myDocument.manufacturingDate;
     print (mdate.getFullYear());

Comment: Yes you can always manipulate returned data from any operation ( MongoDB or otherwise ), but I think the real issue here is why is the OP trying to do something different from what they know works in the first place.

Comment: Not quite Blakes Seven. "why is the OP trying to do something different" is different than what the user asked. The issue specified is "Im trying to display the years of date properties in a mongodb collection." and "...i need a way to take the year out of the ISODate in another way." and "..i hope you have a correct way to do this without aggregate. I prefer the find method but any other method will be good." So that's what I sought to do. But thank you for sharing your opinion.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution helped me!